# Конвертировать статические значения RUB в таблице в динамические EUR и USD с помощью API Центробанка РФ

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

Имеется таблица с статистическими данными в рублях

```js
let json = `{
        "Date": "2021-01-21T11:30:00+03:00",
        "PreviousDate": "2021-01-20T11:30:00+03:00",
        "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2021\/01\/20\/daily_json.js",
        "Timestamp": "2021-01-20T14:00:00+03:00",
        "Valute": {
            "AUD": {
                "ID": "R01010",
                "NumCode": "036",
                "CharCode": "AUD",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
                "Value": 56.7401,
                "Previous": 56.893
            },
            "AZN": {
                "ID": "R01020A",
                "NumCode": "944",
                "CharCode": "AZN",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
                "Value": 43.1754,
                "Previous": 43.3928
            },
            "GBP": {
                "ID": "R01035",
                "NumCode": "826",
                "CharCode": "GBP",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
                "Value": 100.2836,
                "Previous": 100.2282
            },
            "AMD": {
                "ID": "R01060",
                "NumCode": "051",
                "CharCode": "AMD",
                "Nominal": 100,
                "Name": "Армянских драмов",
                "Value": 14.0486,
                "Previous": 14.1183
            },
            "BYN": {
                "ID": "R01090B",
                "NumCode": "933",
                "CharCode": "BYN",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Белорусский рубль",
                "Value": 28.9084,
                "Previous": 28.9274
            },
            "BGN": {
                "ID": "R01100",
                "NumCode": "975",
                "CharCode": "BGN",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Болгарский лев",
                "Value": 45.5423,
                "Previous": 45.6667
            },
            "BRL": {
                "ID": "R01115",
                "NumCode": "986",
                "CharCode": "BRL",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Бразильский реал",
                "Value": 13.6905,
                "Previous": 13.9202
            },
            "HUF": {
                "ID": "R01135",
                "NumCode": "348",
                "CharCode": "HUF",
                "Nominal": 100,
                "Name": "Венгерских форинтов",
                "Value": 24.9227,
                "Previous": 24.8611
            },
            "HKD": {
                "ID": "R01200",
                "NumCode": "344",
                "CharCode": "HKD",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Гонконгских долларов",
                "Value": 94.6309,
                "Previous": 95.1024
            },
            "DKK": {
                "ID": "R01215",
                "NumCode": "208",
                "CharCode": "DKK",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Датская крона",
                "Value": 11.9724,
                "Previous": 12.0078
            },
            "USD": {
                "ID": "R01235",
                "NumCode": "840",
                "CharCode": "USD",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Доллар США",
                "Value": 73.355,
                "Previous": 73.7243
            },
            "EUR": {
                "ID": "R01239",
                "NumCode": "978",
                "CharCode": "EUR",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Евро",
                "Value": 89.1483,
                "Previous": 89.2064
            },
            "INR": {
                "ID": "R01270",
                "NumCode": "356",
                "CharCode": "INR",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Индийских рупий",
                "Value": 10.0392,
                "Previous": 10.0674
            },
            "KZT": {
                "ID": "R01335",
                "NumCode": "398",
                "CharCode": "KZT",
                "Nominal": 100,
                "Name": "Казахстанских тенге",
                "Value": 17.5272,
                "Previous": 17.558
            },
            "CAD": {
                "ID": "R01350",
                "NumCode": "124",
                "CharCode": "CAD",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Канадский доллар",
                "Value": 57.778,
                "Previous": 57.9093
            },
            "KGS": {
                "ID": "R01370",
                "NumCode": "417",
                "CharCode": "KGS",
                "Nominal": 100,
                "Name": "Киргизских сомов",
                "Value": 86.4766,
                "Previous": 87.0417
            },
            "CNY": {
                "ID": "R01375",
                "NumCode": "156",
                "CharCode": "CNY",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Китайский юань",
                "Value": 11.3416,
                "Previous": 11.3628
            },
            "MDL": {
                "ID": "R01500",
                "NumCode": "498",
                "CharCode": "MDL",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Молдавских леев",
                "Value": 42.1338,
                "Previous": 42.5414
            },
            "NOK": {
                "ID": "R01535",
                "NumCode": "578",
                "CharCode": "NOK",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Норвежских крон",
                "Value": 86.2391,
                "Previous": 86.2817
            },
            "PLN": {
                "ID": "R01565",
                "NumCode": "985",
                "CharCode": "PLN",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Польский злотый",
                "Value": 19.6794,
                "Previous": 19.7071
            },
            "RON": {
                "ID": "R01585F",
                "NumCode": "946",
                "CharCode": "RON",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Румынский лей",
                "Value": 18.273,
                "Previous": 18.3243
            },
            "XDR": {
                "ID": "R01589",
                "NumCode": "960",
                "CharCode": "XDR",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "СДР (специальные права заимствования)",
                "Value": 105.6239,
                "Previous": 106.1925
            },
            "SGD": {
                "ID": "R01625",
                "NumCode": "702",
                "CharCode": "SGD",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Сингапурский доллар",
                "Value": 55.3247,
                "Previous": 55.4485
            },
            "TJS": {
                "ID": "R01670",
                "NumCode": "972",
                "CharCode": "TJS",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Таджикских сомони",
                "Value": 64.3747,
                "Previous": 64.6988
            },
            "TRY": {
                "ID": "R01700J",
                "NumCode": "949",
                "CharCode": "TRY",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Турецких лир",
                "Value": 98.52,
                "Previous": 98.7864
            },
            "TMT": {
                "ID": "R01710A",
                "NumCode": "934",
                "CharCode": "TMT",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Новый туркменский манат",
                "Value": 20.9886,
                "Previous": 21.0942
            },
            "UZS": {
                "ID": "R01717",
                "NumCode": "860",
                "CharCode": "UZS",
                "Nominal": 10000,
                "Name": "Узбекских сумов",
                "Value": 69.8565,
                "Previous": 70.2082
            },
            "UAH": {
                "ID": "R01720",
                "NumCode": "980",
                "CharCode": "UAH",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Украинских гривен",
                "Value": 26.054,
                "Previous": 26.1531
            },
            "CZK": {
                "ID": "R01760",
                "NumCode": "203",
                "CharCode": "CZK",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Чешских крон",
                "Value": 34.098,
                "Previous": 34.1854
            },
            "SEK": {
                "ID": "R01770",
                "NumCode": "752",
                "CharCode": "SEK",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Шведских крон",
                "Value": 87.8871,
                "Previous": 88.2081
            },
            "CHF": {
                "ID": "R01775",
                "NumCode": "756",
                "CharCode": "CHF",
                "Nominal": 1,
                "Name": "Швейцарский франк",
                "Value": 82.6628,
                "Previous": 82.9295
            },
            "ZAR": {
                "ID": "R01810",
                "NumCode": "710",
                "CharCode": "ZAR",
                "Nominal": 10,
                "Name": "Южноафриканских рэндов",
                "Value": 49.306,
                "Previous": 48.8674
            },
            "KRW": {
                "ID": "R01815",
                "NumCode": "410",
                "CharCode": "KRW",
                "Nominal": 1000,
                "Name": "Вон Республики Корея",
                "Value": 66.5995,
                "Previous": 66.8007
            },
            "JPY": {
                "ID": "R01820",
                "NumCode": "392",
                "CharCode": "JPY",
                "Nominal": 100,
                "Name": "Японских иен",
                "Value": 70.7002,
                "Previous": 70.8922
            }
        }
    }`;


//$.getJSON('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js'), function(data) {
//    
//});

let usdBtn = document.querySelector('.usd'),
  parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

usdBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.price_cell').forEach(item => {
    item.textContent = Math.ceil(item.textContent / parsedJSON.Valute.USD.Value) + "$";
  })
})
```

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      NAME
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      PRICE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      PRODUCT1
    </div>
    <div class="cell price_cell">
      100
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      PRODUCT2
    </div>
    <div class="cell price_cell">
      200
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="usd">$</button>
<button class="eur">€</button>
```

На данный момент при нажатии кнопки "$" скрипт конвертирует значения RUB в таблице и выводит их в USD согласно курсу [ЦБ из json](https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js)

Необходимо поправить код скрипта, с возможностью парсинга курса валют из json и конвертацией таблицы в EUR при нажатии кнопки "€"

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s20pe7at/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из разметки, формулы пересчёта и условий в вопросе, должно быть как-то так:

```js
let json = `{
    "Date": "2021-01-21T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousDate": "2021-01-20T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2021\/01\/20\/daily_json.js",
    "Timestamp": "2021-01-20T14:00:00+03:00",
    "Valute": {
        "USD": {
            "ID": "R01235",
            "NumCode": "840",
            "CharCode": "USD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Доллар США",
            "Value": 73.355,
            "Previous": 73.7243
        },
        "EUR": {
            "ID": "R01239",
            "NumCode": "978",
            "CharCode": "EUR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Евро",
            "Value": 89.1483,
            "Previous": 89.2064
        },
        "JPY": {
            "ID": "R01820",
            "NumCode": "392",
            "CharCode": "JPY",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Японских иен",
            "Value": 70.7002,
            "Previous": 70.8922
        }
    }
}`;


//$.getJSON('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js'), function(data) {
//    
//});
let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json),
  aPrices = [...document.querySelectorAll('.price_cell')];

aPrices.forEach(item => {
  item.dataset.originalPrice = item.textContent
});

function fReCalc(sValute, sChar) {
  aPrices.forEach(item => {
    item.textContent = Math.ceil(parseFloat(item.dataset.originalPrice) / parseFloat(parsedJSON.Valute[sValute].Value)) + sChar
  });
}

document.querySelector('.usd').addEventListener('click', fReCalc.bind(this, 'USD', '$'));
document.querySelector('.eur').addEventListener('click', fReCalc.bind(this, 'EUR', '€'));
document.querySelector('.jpy').addEventListener('click', fReCalc.bind(this, 'JPY', '¥'));
```

```css
.table { width: 300px; }
.row { display: flex; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%; }
.cell { width: 50%; padding: 10px; margin: 0 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">NAME</div><div class="cell">PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">PRODUCT1</div><div class="cell price_cell">1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">PRODUCT2</div><div class="cell price_cell">2000</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="usd">$</button>
<button class="eur">€</button>
<button class="jpy">¥</button>
```

В примере подсократил лишние валюты. Добавлять по аналогии - кнопка с классом и обработчик для неё с данными для выборки.